# How to assign multiple datatypes to a variable in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I have this piece of code:

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
    owner: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Worker' }

})
```

Here the "ref" can either have "worker" or "client". So how to assign both possibilities to the "owner" variable in mongodb. Can we use "or" clause here?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Schema types Mixed](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) might meet your requirements

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
     owner: {
             type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
             content: Mixed 
     }
})
```